# can we set the cronExpression during runtime

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

my spring application context have cronTrigger

```
 <bean id="cronTriggerJobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobA" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/60 * * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

can we set the cronExpression during the runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

though I am not sure.. but this thread might help

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?31736-Setting-dynamic-Property